# How to customize email subject via emailOutputTo in Laravel schedule call

Tags: laravel

I'm running tasks via the Laravel scheduler and emailing the results, which is possible because:

> The emailOutputTo is exclusive to the command and exec methods.

Logic:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    printf("Performing Purge... \n");
    printf("Purge completed! \n");
})->everyMinute()
  ->emailOutputTo('email@mail.com');
```

The subject line is always:

> Scheduled Job Output For []

and it's not clear or documented as to how we can customize the email subject line.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is still looking for a solution: Use the "name" function to set the title of the email message, e.g.:

```
   $schedule->command('backup:database')->daily()->name("Nightly Backup")
      ->emailOutputTo('admin@yourwebsite.com');
```

This will set the title of the email message to "Nightly Backup".  This will also become
the name of the running command reported by artisan schedule:run, e.g.:

```
   > php artisan schedule:run
   Running scheduled command: Nightly Backup
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any documentation though, But when I dug the framework code,

in `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php`

the `emailOutput()` function calls the following function

```
 protected function getEmailSubject()
 {
     if ($this->description) {
            return $this->description;
     }

     return "Scheduled Job Output For [{$this->command}]";
 }
```

and this `$description` is a public property on The `Event` Class as well, so if you can assign the description somehow, it will work.

I will update this answer once I have solid answer, meanwhile this could lead you.

Comment: trying to find an exact answer, i will update it once i get it

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a simple as:

```php
$schedule->command('backup:database')->daily()->name("Nightly Backup")
    ->emailOutputTo('admin@yourwebsite.com')
    ->description('The subject of the mail');
```